# how to define a cut-off point in temperature distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I have a temperature variable in my data. I want to exclude the highest temperature days. The reason behind exluding hottest days is that those hottest days dont distort real association with the outcome.

For that, I want to look at the distribution of temperature, select the highest temperature and then decide a cut point where the data becomes more and more sparse.

My question is do I have to look at temperature distribution manually in R and decide the cutoff points? (criteria for the cutoff point is: where the data become more and more sparse)?

My data looks like this. In this 25.3 is the highest temperature. How can i define where the data below is becoming more sparse? what could be the cutoff point in following example?

```
    13.7
    14.1
    15.0
    15.4
    15.2
    14.9
    15.0
    15.5
    17.4
    20.0
    20.9
    20.7
    23.1
    25.3
    24.0
    19.8
    17.3
    19.1
    21.8
    23.0
    23.7
    23.0
    22.2
    20.4
    18.1
    17.2
    16.4
    16.6
    17.5
    18.9
    20.0
    20.1
    22.4
```

What Does "sparse" actually mean ? is that where the data starts to become wider and wider?

Comment: I'll let you decide what "sparse" means in your context. But one way of choosing a cutoff point would be taking XX% of the `max(temp)`.

Comment: What is the meaning of the first column, with values from 939 to 971? If this is not relevant, it would be simpler just to remove it from the description of the dataset.

Comment: I deleted the first column, Thanks for the suggestion.